# Center the object in button click

Tags: three.js

Here I'm trying to center the object in button click hen it is pan-ned to different location. So I have tried by resetting the camera location where it just bought up the object to the starting position but my need is to bring the object to center of the screen when clicked the button in any rotated position.
https://jsfiddle.net/Ajay_Venkatesh/thpb8csv/4/

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var cube, cube_geometry, cube_material;
var controls;

init();
render();

function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // renderer

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // camera

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 12;

    // controls

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.addEventListener('change', render);
    controls.enableZoom = false;

    // mesh - cube

    cube_geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5, 5, 5);

    for (var i = 0; i < cube_geometry.faces.length; i += 2) {

        var color = Math.random() * 0xffffff;

        cube_geometry.faces[i].color.setHex(color);
        cube_geometry.faces[i + 1].color.setHex(color);
    }

    cube_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors
    });

    cube = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry, cube_material);
    scene.add(cube);

    // Lights

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(light);

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x002288);
    light.position.set(-1, -1, -1);
    scene.add(light);

    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
    scene.add(light);

    // events

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function render() {

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function onWindowResize(event) {

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

}
```

Comment: Are you aware that your fiddle throws runtime error when clicking on "Back to position". Here is a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/e2b5v84g/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mugen87 . What you have done is you have reset the camera position. But all I need is to just bring back the object to center without changing the position of the object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code should do what you want. When clicking the button, the cube's rotation will change so it looks towards the camera. It's important to call `render()` since you don't have an animation loop in your app.

```
button.addEventListener( 'click', ( event ) => {

    cube.lookAt( camera.position );
    render();

} );
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g91y0ks8/

Comment: Yes you almost got my issue. I mean center of the screen not center of the cube. Thanks for the reply @Mugen87

Comment: How about this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r8tm1q3v/. The cube is not position in the screen center even if you perform panning.